# How do i properly cache common objects / entities when using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have a web app that needs to load some rows from tables in my database as objects that will be re-used in various places within the application.

For instance, I might retrieve a list of locations that change infrequently, so I want to store those in memory for quicker access later on.

Next, in a future request, I want to associate one of these entities to another entity in the database; however, JPA throws errors when attempting to save, because the cached entity is detached.

How do I reattach the cached entity so I can include it in the current transaction?

I'm using the Apache OpenJPA implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `EntityManager.merge()` will re-attach a Detached object.

Have a look at this informative [page](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html)

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't seem to like that the object has an "ID" value. On my entity, ID is the PK and has a @GeneratedValue annotation.

The error is: `The instance life cycle is in PNewState state and hence an existing non-default value for the identity field is not permitted. You either need to remove the @GeneratedValue annotation or modify the code to remove the initializer processing.`

Setting the ID to 0 clears the error, but results in a new record for this entity, which I do not want. Existing record needs to be related.